# Use varbinary as foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Is it ok to use data type varbinary for foreign keys?
Why?
I have an EvalAnswer table with a FK to a Score table.
The score is sensitive and should be encrypted. The encrypt/decrypt happens in the asp.net (4.0) project and not in sql server (2008), so the data type needs to be varbinary.

EDIT: more info

Of course. 
I have these columns: Id, Score, ScoreText, Description, Index
The Id is an incremental counter. (PK)
The Score is the score as number (such as 1).
The ScoreText is the score as a letter (Score 1 equals letter A).
The Description is a comment for every score.

The reason I have it like this is also that there are special situations, 
such as one of the questions have only scoring from 1-4, and the rest has 1-5.

So every question has a score 1, but the the description differs from another questions score 1.
So If I have 5 questions, this gives 5*5 rows in the Score table. (All with different description)

When I page load I get the correct scoring (with description) for every dropdownlist. Normally 1-5.
But when the user has saved the scoring, I need to know the earlier saaved score for every question when I page load.
Therefore I have a relation between EvalAnswer and the scoring.

There are questions with relation to the score table which is NOT sensitive.
But some are. And for them I need to hide the relation beetween EvalAnswer and Score.

What might be a bad design is the fact that I use the same table (the score table) as the
one to show the available scoring for every questions. 
and also as the one to hold what the user has chosen. (this is the FK from EvalAnswer to Score)

Please advice.......

Comment: It is not against the law, but it is a _very_ bad idea.

Comment: Ok, why is it a bad idea? 
Please recommend other solution. If you need more info about my design, please ask.

Comment: OK. Please explain why you need to join on a score?

Comment: Your question doesn't convey why you need the varbinary as a foreign key. It's a bad idea to use any non-fixed length value as a foreign key or primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding an `ID int` column to the Score table and reference this field from the `EvalAnswer` table.

This means your table scripts will change to

```
CREATE TABLE Score (
   Id int not null identity primary key
 , Code varbinary(max)  --> The new field containing the encrypted information
 , Score int
 , ScoreText varchar(5)
 , Description varchar(max)
 , Index int) 

CREATE TABLE EvalAnswer (
   Id int not null identity,
   ScoreId int not null references Score(Id)
   ...
)
```

As you can see, the "Old" `Id` field has now become the `Code` field. The new field is an `identity` column containing a unique number

There is nothing against using a `varbinary` column in a foreign key, but it will make querying and debugging much harder.

Also note there is a 900 byte limit on the width of an index which might be easier to hit when storing an encrypted blob.

Comment: Hi Filip I already have a ref from EvalAnswer to Score. And this Id that I have is the one I need to protect. But I need to crypt/decrypt in asp.net app. So I need to have the column changed to a varbinary instead, and therefore my question. So, there are no other way than to use my FK as varbinary then?

Comment: So you have 2 foreign keys from EvalAnswer to the Score table?

Comment: No I have only one. Im not sure where I misunderstood you.
But it still needs to be varbinary.

Comment: Hi. I have seen your update.
Im confused now. Maybe what I look for cannot be done.
Im protecting data from anyone who has access to the database server.
They will still see the relation between the two tables, and therefore the users score.

When the user visits the page for the first time the dropdownlist is databound to the values 1-5.
Showing score 0 as default. The user saves score 3. 
The FK in EvalAnswer points to that row in the Score table.
So the score 1 to 5 is visible in my Score column, right?
What am I protecting in the new Code column?

Thanks

Comment: encrypting the value does not help that. Save a new record and find the matching ones to know what a value means (without decrypting). To really protect it you have to save the encrypted (and salted) result in the EvalAnswer table.

Comment: Hi
You mean that I have a Score column in EvalAnswer which holds the score, and no relation to the Score table? I guess I can try that.
But I use the score column as the actual score (1-5), so that I can get average score etc in different reports. And I use ScoreText as the text used in the dropdownlist. Currently A to E.
If user choses B, I save score 2 to the new column in EvalAnswer, is it what you mean?

Thanks